# org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring-test

The error show up when My code like this:

```
@Test
public void getTemplateByIdTest() throws Exception {
    client.get().uri("/template/getTemplate/7")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .expectBody(VtTemplateVO.class)
            .returnResult();
}
```

When I change my code like this,it's ok!

```
@Test
public void getTemplateByIdTest() throws Exception {
    client.get().uri("/template/getTemplate/7")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .expectBody(String.class)
            .returnResult();
}
```

Why when I use `.expectBody(VtTemplateVO.class)` it will say `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported`

Somebody knows? please help,thanks

Comment: Seems like server endpoint ("/template/getTemplate/7") does not accept such content type. Google it how to fix endpoint to accept "application/json;charset=UTF-8" enconding. ```@RequestMapping(value="/pets", headers="Content-Type=application/json")``` maybe will work :)

Comment: Thanks for comment so quick,but when I use `.expectBody(String.class)` ,the header is 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' too , the second Test is pass.So I think it's not the problem.

Comment: To anyone else searching for it even after setting same content type, ensure to check more logs. There will be some jackson deserialization issues which you have to fix.

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing this issue caused by Jackson.There needs to be a default constructor for the VtTemplateVO.class with annotated properties. Ex. what I did-

```
@JsonCreator
public Comment(@JsonProperty("id")String id, @JsonProperty("text")String text, @JsonProperty("createdTime") LocalDate createdTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.createdTime = createdTime;
}
```

Hope it works for you as well. :)

Comment: Yeah. This answer should be higher up on search results. Saved my day

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, any problem in creating and populating the object might result in this error.

In my case, I had duplicated `@JsonProperty`, example:

```
public class MyObject {
  @JsonProperty("foo")
  private String foo;

  @JsonProperty("foo")
  private String bar;
}
```

So I fixed to:

```
public class MyObject {
  @JsonProperty("foo")
  private String foo;

  @JsonProperty("bar")
  private String bar;
}
```

And it worked.

But I've seen other people commenting that other mistakes might result in this error, like:

- Not having setter methods
- Having overloaded setters
- Not having a default constructor

Comment: Glad I saw your answer, else could have wasted a lot more time

Comment: Glad I saw your answer, it brought me to the right path to find the solution to my problem: I needed overloaded setters, and I avoided them by defining the attribute as Object, and then casting to the correct value in the getter method (in my case, it was either a String or a List<String>: depending on whether the value  received from the Json was a JsonObject or a JsonArray). See more on this issue also on my answers in another Stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219012/5538923 .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of annotating every parameter with `@JsonProperty`, you can also compile your code with the `-parameters` flag (since Java 8). This will retain the parameter names in the bytecode thus allowing Jackson to use them. See the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs)

```
<compilerArgs>
  <arg>-parameters</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

You should also consider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44075684/2145769 that now parameter names become part of your API.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was caused by duplicated @Jsonproperty values, as Jefferson Lima pointed in his answer. I can't see your VtTemplateVO POJO class in your question but it might cause the problem.

In my case, I tried to unpack several nested values from "game" JSON node in my POJO class to get the desired mapping schema when this exception occurred.

```
"game": {
  "home_team_id": 2
  "visitor_team_id": 5
}
```

The following approach didn't work.

```
public class MyPojo {

  @JsonProperty("game")
  public void unpackHomeTeamId(Map<String, String> game) {
      homeTeamId = game.get("home_team_id");
  }

  @JsonProperty("game")
  public void unpackAwayTeamId(Map<String, String> game) {
      awayTeamId = game.get("visitor_team_id");
  }
}
```

The solution was setting all fields in one method thus avoiding confusing  Jackson mapper. It also led me to a more concise design.

```
@JsonProperty("game")
public void unpackNestedGameProperties(Map<String, String> game) {
    homeTeamId = game.get("home_team_id");
    awayTeamId = game.get("visitor_team_id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the following dependency can cause the same exception

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I caught now, that such error occurs when something wrong during deserialization. Check your mapping class.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

as

```
webClientBuilder.build()
                .post()
                .uri(ccpApiUrl)
                //.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(customerRequest)
                .exchange()
                .doOnSuccess(
                            clientResponse -> logger.info("clientResponse.headers() = " + clientResponse.headers())
                            )
                .doOnSuccess(
                        clientResponse -> {
                    logger.info("clientResponse.statusCode() = " + clientResponse.statusCode());
                    getStatus(clientResponse.statusCode());

                            })
                //.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(CcpResponse.class))
                // .retryWhen(fixedRetry)
                .block();
```