# Getting error UnsupportedMediaTypeException when trying to update maven dependency to spring-webflux from spring-boot-starter-webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-webflux

As I am trying to update **spring-webflux** dependency from **spring-boot-starter-webflux** in maven. My working code start giving error like"

From :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

changed to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting below Error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json' not supported for bodyType=com.location.of.Object at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters.unsupportedError(BodyInserters.java:391)
```

**Note :** I am trying Jackson library for POJO and having constructor in that.
What could be issue? How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514296/org-springframework-web-reactive-function-unsupportedmediatypeexception-content)

Comment: @123 I tried this solution. I am trying Jackson library for POJO and having constructor in that. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of missing Jeckson dependency which I have't included in my project's submodule. I added the dependency in child module and it worked. Thanks all.